# Changing value of combobox without triggering change event, possible?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I want to change the value of a combobox without triggering the `_change()` event.

```
For i = 1 to 4
    Sheets("GrafVal" & i).DatumArTill = Sheets("GrafVal1").DatumArTill
Next i
```

`DatumArTill` is the name of the combobox. There are four of them with the same name located on four different sheets. (GrafVal1, GrafVal2, GrafVal3 and GrafVal4) The code above is located in all four comboboxes `_change()` event. When I change the value of one, I want all to change their value. But when they do, they trigger each others `_change()` event, causing a chain reaction. Is it possible to just change the value of a combobox in code without triggering its `_change()` event?

Comment: Try `Application.EnableEvents` = False

Comment: I added ```Application.EnableEvents = False``` before the for loop but when the loop got to 2 and changed the combobox on the ```GrafVal2``` sheet it still triggered its change event.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is to set a global variable like `isLoading`.
That is how I do for my controls so they don't trigger while the form is loading.
And add to each controll:
`If isLoading = False then ..`

Comment: Thank you! I actually solved it using a global variable. ```SourceComboBox``` If I change the 2nd ComboBox it first set the variable to 2 and then at the end of the change event to 0. Every change event starts with the code ```If SourceComboBox = 0 then```